# How to change a column into one date format if you have two different format?

Tags: python, date, google-colaboratory

So, I have a column date with two different date format such as these:

`1/2/2011`

`13-01-2011`

I have code :

```
superstore['Order Month'] = superstore['Order Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime('%m/%Y'))
```

Google Colab return

```
ValueError: time data '13-01-2011' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if` statement to check which format is in each entry and apply the correct one. For example:

```
def convert(x):
    date_format = "%d/%m/%Y" if '/' in x else "%d-%m-%Y"
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, date_format).strftime('%m/%Y')
    
superstore['Order Month'] = superstore['Order Date'].apply(convert)
```